# Get Specific Content of PDF in PHP and Codeigniter

Tags: php, pdf, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to extract text from a PDF and get some specific data inside the PDF content.

What I wanted to get are 
Name, Address, Email, Contact #, etc. I already extracted text in a pdf file but stack on getting the data which contains Name, Address, etc only.

Here's a example of the extracted string from the pdf.

[image]

What i want is to get the value of the name, address, and contact only.
For example:

**NAME: Cabatay John
ADDRESS: #208**

is there any possible solution to extract this strings? Thank you!

Here's my code for parsing the PDF file.

```
        $parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
        $pdf    = $parser->parseFile(base_url('public/uploads/'.$upload['file_name']));

        $text = $pdf->getText();

        echo $text;
```

library used: http://www.pdfparser.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that you already extracted the pdf's text as a string, you can then process it and extract whatever you need with php functions .. something like this:

```
$name_and_address = strstr($pdf_string, 'CONTACT', true);
```

This will return everything before the first occurence of the word `"contact"` and that's what you want in this case supposingly this will always be the same pattern.